# What is a pre-order that is not reflexive nor irreflexive?

Tags: order-theory

What is a pre-order that is not reflexive nor irreflexive? so just transitive and total. What is this relation called?

I am aware that [total pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders) is transitive, total, and reflexive.

But I am wondering is there a variation of it that not reflexive nor irreflexive?

Comment: Pre-orders are reflexive (and transitive) by definition (and don't have to be total). Do you mean a transitive relation that is neither reflexive nor irreflexive?

Comment: Transitive + total. What is it called?

Comment: A total transitive relation? I don't know of any special name for it, and couldn't immediately find one online.

Answer (score 1):

I would call your construction simply a **total [transitive order](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transitive+relation)**. Transitivity is the absolute minimum requirement for a binary relation to qualify as an [order](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/order).

Alternatively, it could be called a **thin, connected [semicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory)**. The *thin* part accounts for the fact that your semicategory has only one morphism between objects, and the *connected* part accounts for the totality of your order.

Does this answer your question, or even make sense? If not, happy to edit it to improve.